# extract columns from csv to a text file

Tags: awk, csv

It is a simple problem. I have a csv file with multiple columns I would like to extract 3 columns and save the output to a text file.

sample of my dataset:

```
page_id     post_name   link        post_type       likes_count
5550296508  Ben Carson  www.cnn.com shared_story    192583
5830242058  John Smith  www.abc.com news_story      467
9485676544  Sara John   www.msc.com shared_story    462
```

I would like to select three columns and save them to a text file with a comma seperator.The desired output: (or any similar format that shows the columns in a neat way. it doesn't have to be exactly like this format)

```
"page_id","post_name","post_type"
"5550296508","Ben Carson","shared_story"
"5830242058","John Smith", "news_story" 
"9485676544", "Sara John",  "shared_story"
```

I tried to use `awk`:

```
awk -F',' '{print $1,$2,$4}' Data.csv > output.txt
```

It returns this output with a blank space between the columns, I would like to replace the blank space with a comma:

```
page_id     post_name   post_type 
5550296508  Ben Carson  shared_story    
5830242058  John Smith  news_story   
9485676544  Sara John   shared_story
```

I tried `printf` but I am not sure I am using the correct string because it doesn't return the output I want.

```
awk '{printf "%s,%s,%s", $1,$2,$4}' Data.csv > output.txt
```

using `sed`. This only replaces the first blank with a comma.

```
awk -F',' '{print $2,$5,$10}' Data.csv | sed 's/ /,/' > output.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below command to separate it out with comma `,` :

```
awk '{print $1","$2","$4}' Data.csv > output.txt
```

Output Will be :

```
page_id,post_name,post_type
5550296508,Ben,www.cnn.com
5830242058,John,www.abc.com
9485676544,Sara,www.msc.com
```

Comment: this worked, thanks! I just had to add `-F','`

Answer (score 1):

Your input file is **not** comma-separated.  I am guessing that it is tab-separated.  If that is the case, then try:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{print "\""$1,$2,$4"\""}' OFS='","' Data.csv
"page_id","post_name","post_type"
"5550296508","Ben Carson","shared_story"
"5830242058","John Smith","news_story"
"9485676544","Sara John","shared_story"
```

If that is not quite it, then try:

```
awk -F'\t+' '{print "\""$1,$2,$4"\""}' OFS='","' Data.csv
```

#### How it works

- `-F'\t'` tells awk to use tab as the field separator.  Alternatively, `-F'\t+'` tells awk to use any sequence of one or more field tabs as a field separator.
- `print "\""$1,$2,$4"\""` tells awk to print a double-quote, followed by field 1 followed by a field separator followed by field 2 followed by a field separator followed by field 4 followed by a double-quote.
- `OFS='","'` tells awk to use `","` as the field separator on output.

Comment: it works too. And the output looks very neat. Thank you John. I just had to replace the tab delimiter with a comma.`-F','`

Comment: @leena Very good.  Your observation is curious, though:  Your sample input, as shown in the question ("sample of my dataset"), has no commas in it all.

Comment: yes I didn't reflect the sample dataset in the best way. Thanks for your help